# C#/.NET iterator with Eof/Eol/EndOfInput property

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I need to parse command line with complex arguments. Each argument can contain 0 or more sub-arguments. I started with this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var argIterator = ((IEnumerable<string>)args).GetEnumerator();
        ParseArguments(argIterator);
    }
```

However this proved to be not enough, because at any given moment I need to know whether I'm at EndOfInput or not. While [MoveNext()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns false, this can happen anywhere during parse, and `IEnumerator` gives me no clue that this happened, except that a call to [Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) throws an exception. I don't think this deserves creation of a custom enumeration class.

The trick I'm using is to add all strings into a new array with `args.length + 1` elements. The additional element is `null`. Then I can have this extension method:

```
static class EnumeratorExtension
{
    private static bool EndOfInput(this IEnumerator<string> iterator)
    {
        return iterator.Current == null;
    }

}
```

At any time, I can call `iterator.EndOfInput()` and know precisely if all arguments were visited. However this pollutes `IEnumerator` and doesn't work for any collection (requires `null` only at the end).

This seems to be a common need. Is there a better solution?

Comment: What's wrong with using the `args` as an array and passing that into `ParseArguments`.  Then you can use a `for` loop in there, and utilize the `Length` property on the array to determine if you are parsing the last argument?

Comment: This requires passing a `ref int index` along all parser methods. Getting current element will always be `args[index]` (two values instead of a single value `iterator.Current`). The test for Eol will be `index >= args.length`, again uses two values. I prefer having a single object that represents an iterator.

Comment: Why not just move the loop out of the `ParseArguments` then? Then use `ParseArgument(args[i]);` inside the loop.

Comment: Could you post more of your code, like `ParseArguments` and one of the functions it calls, so we can better see what you are attempting to do.  An example argument string would be helpful as well--especially one with the sub-arguments

Comment: The ParseArguments() method is only the tip of iceberg. Arguments can have sub-arguments, which are parsed by other parse methods (ParseOptionFoo(iterator), ParseOptionK9(iterator), etc). It doesn't seem good to pass args and index everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `IEnumerator` as it is designed to be used.

The contract that `IEnumerator` specifies that when you call `MoveNext()` a value of `true` means "I have a value and it is in `Current`" and `false` means "I have no more values".

If you want a method that allows you to call `Current` when `MoveNext()` returns `false` you will need to write something else (since that doesn't match `IEnumerator`'s contract.

For instance you could skip calling your other handlers or pass them a `null` object.

Comment: I don't want to call `Current`. I only want to know if the iterator is past last item. I'm sure it has this information because it holds `index` and `args` so it can check index against `args.length`.

Comment: @fernacolo: That is an implementation detail. The interface only provides `Current` and `MoveNext()`, thus those are the only things you are allowed to ask about.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, it's better to use a for-loop. Enumerators are not designed for what you are doing.

You can do something like this instead:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (string arg in args)
    {
        ParseArgument(arg);  // Parse each argument individually.
    }
}
```

If you need sub-arguments, then you can split your logic into multiple methods:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ParseArguments(args);
}

static void ParseArguments(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
    {
        switch (args[i])
        {
            // Single arguments. (No sub-arguments)
            case "/a":
            case "/b":
            case "/c":
                ParseArgument(args[i]);  // Parse individual argument(s)
                break;

            // Double-arguments (1 sub-argument)
            case "/username":
            case "/password":
            case "/filepath":
                string nextArg = (i + 1 < args.Length ? args[i + 1] : null);
                ParseArgument(args[i], nextArg);  // Parse individual argument(s)
                i++;
                break;

            // Triple-arguments (2 sub-arguments)
            case "/makeAndModel":
            case "/nameAndAddress":
                string nextArg = (i + 1 < args.Length ? args[i + 1] : null);
                string nextArg2 = (i + 2 < args.Length ? args[i + 2] : null);
                ParseArgument(args[i], nextArg, nextArg2);  // Parse individual argument(s)
                i += 2;
                break;

            // Invalid arguments
            default:
                ShowHelp();
                break;
    }
}

// Parse individual argument(s)
static void ParseArgument(params string[] args)
{
    ...
}
```

Note that you can also implement `ParseArgument(params string[] args)` in other ways, such as 3 different overloaded methods, each with a different number of arguments; Or you can implement a method for each argument (eg. `ParseUserName`, `ParsePassword`, etc.)

---

**EDIT:** If you need to a varying number of sub-arguments and you do not know how many of them ahead of time (eg. number of sub-arguments dependent on the actual content of the arguments), then you can do the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int parsedCount = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < args.Length; index += parsedCount)
    {
        parsedCount = ParseArguments(args);
    }
}

static int ParseArguments (string[] args, int index)
{
    ...
}
```

The above is still better than using an enumerator.

Comment: Thanks, but my question states that arguments can have variable number of sub-arguments and your answer is not taking that into account.

Comment: Updated as per your requirements

Comment: Thanks for effort. I know I can do stuff like this. That's exactly what I DON'T want to do. I want iterator to make code easy to read and you are not satisfying the readability requirement. Also, you are considering a single level of sub-parameters, there can be more than that. The only way I could work with an `int` index is by passing `ref int index` to all my sub-parsers, as I told in a previous comment. Which I find worst than having something like iterator.

Comment: I would humbly disagree. The method above separates the parsing logic to two, one for extracting the arguments out, and one for parsing the actual content. This makes it much more readable. Using enumerator will definitely make it much harder to understand.

Comment: I've updated my answer again for another scenario that probably matches your requirements better.